# Select item by probably

Tags: java

I am currently trying to make a probably based choose system in java, but it doesn't seem to work that well, my current code looks like this:

```
private ArrayList<SelectableObjekt> obs;
obs = new ArrayList<>();
obs.add(new SelectableObjekt("hello, with 3% probably", 30)); //Will be devied in the SelectableObjekt class by 10 so 30 will become 3% and 700 will become 70%
obs.add(new SelectableObjekt("hello, with 70% probably", 700));
obs.add(new SelectableObjekt("hello, with 90% probably", 900));
obs.sort(new Comparator<SelectableObjekt>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(SelectableObjekt o1, SelectableObjekt o2) {

            return Double.compare(o1.getChance(), o2.getChance());
        }
    });
```

and to select the Object:

```
private SelectableObjekt selectRandom() {
    double perc = ((int)ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1001))/10D;
    for (int i = 0; i < obs.size(); i++) {
        SelectableObjekt obj = obs.get(i);
        if(obj.getChance() > perc) {
            return obj;
        }
    }
    return obs.get(chestDrops.size()-1);
}
```

In summary, the SelectableObjekt contains a chance int inside that can be 0.1-100. 100 meaning 100% so 32.3 means 32.3%, but the selection doesn't work properly and I get 70% more often than 90%, I cant get my head around why this happens.

Comment: Do you mean 7, rather than 70? Otherwise your percentages  don't add up to 100.

Comment: What is `chestDrops`. and why are you using random when you want higher priority and your array is sorted with priority, simply ask for last one.

Comment: According to your logic, you should get 70 more often than 90. Because you have a 40% chance to get 70 and only 20% chance to get 90.

Comment: @AndyTurner the percentages arent supose to add up to 100 if no item is selected the last item(last item allways has the highest probably) will be selected

Comment: @Juliusmauser you can't select one with 3% probability, one with 70% probability and one with 90% probability. If you pick an item, you have 100% chance of picking an item, which is the sum of the probabilities of picking each specific item. Based on your current approach, you will get them with 3%, 67% and 30% probabilities (ish).

Comment: @AndyTurner so, i have to make sure that the probabilitys add up to 100 and then it wood work?

Comment: @Juliusmauser not quite. You also have to decrement `perc` by `obj.chance` in the for loop, if the condition is not matched.

Answer (score 0):

The way the code is written is not unusual. You have three ranges.

```
0 - 3% - the first option
3 - 70% - the second option.
70 - 90% - the third option.
90 - 100% - also the third option.
```

This means the "70%" option should be ~67% of the time, and the "90%" option is ~30% of the time.

Comment: @ccjmne There is no 50% of 50%. The random value is determined only once. Three of 50% would result in the first one 50% of the time, and last by default 50% of the time.